Mongo indexes with arrays of objects behave differently according to how many array's fields I query
I can't get mongo index work with multiple array's fields.
Mongo version: 6
I've got a huge database with billions of docs. For practical reasons, I've created a new test dummy database with a couple of docs, to see how mongo behaves with indexes.
Here's a list of docs I have:
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "deleted": true,
  "a": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "l1": 1,
      "l2": "123",
      "l3": 456,
      "l4": "value"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  "a": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "l1": "1",
      "l2": 123,
      "l3": 456,
      "l4": "value"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
  },
  "d": "val_d",
  "e": "val_e"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
  },
  "a": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "l1": "1",
      "l2": 123,
      "l3": 456,
      "l4": "value"
    }
  ]
}]

If you see, there's a doc which is completely different from the others, meaning that "a" and "list" may be missing, together with "deleted", and more frequent docs are the kinds of with "d" and "e".
Anyway, My original query that I'm troubleshooting is
query = {
      "list.l1": "1",
      "list.l4": "value",
      "deleted": {
        "$exists": false
      },
      "a": 1,
      "list.l3": {
        "$gte": 456
      },
      "list.l2": {
        "$lte": 123
      },
    }

Since changing order in query and indexes didn't solve docsExamined read != 0, I've decided to start from scratch, with one field at a time, starting with list.l1.
If I just query on "list.l1":"1"  and create index on "list.l1:1", it works perfectly fine, COUNT_SCAN as stage, only keysExamined, boundaries perfect:
indexBounds: {
          startKey: {
            'list.l1': '1'
          },
          startKeyInclusive: true,
          endKey: {
            'list.l1': '1'
          },
          endKeyInclusive: true
        }

Note: using $elemMatch instead of exact match, on the list.l1, won't use the index, and list.l1 gets FETCHed (why?)
Problems arrive as I add also list.l4 to the query and to the index: the latter is not used by mongo, (list.l1:1, list.l4:1), while the former is:
indexBounds: {
            'list.l1': [
              '["1", "1"]'
            ]
          },

inputStage: {
        stage: 'FETCH',
        filter: {
          'list.l4': {
            '$eq': 'value'
          }
        },


 totalKeysExamined: 3,
    totalDocsExamined: 3,

If I try to hint the latest index on both fields, I get
indexBounds: {
            'list.l1': [
              '["1", "1"]'
            ],
            'list.l4': [
              '[MinKey, MaxKey]'
            ]
          },


inputStage: {
        stage: 'FETCH',
        filter: {
          'list.l4': {
            '$eq': 'value'
          }
        },

totalKeysExamined: 3,
    totalDocsExamined: 3,

Since I'm already getting troubles with just 2 fields, it doesn't make sense to me to investigate on my billion-doc db with other fields, as it already behaves bad on just 2 fields.
Is there something going on with array fields?

Does list ever contain more than one entry?

@user20042973 for now it may only contain one element, if list exists. don't know if it may contain more in the future

I think there may be some misconceptions about how arrays are indexed and queried.
Consider this collection of 4 documents.  In 1-3 the "arry" field contains an array of 2 documents, in the #4 "arry" contains an object.
[
  {"arry": [ // #1
      {"f1": "red","f2": "left"},
      {"f1": "blue","f2": "up"}
  ]},
  {"arry": [ //#2
      {"f1": "red","f2": "right"},
      {"f1": "green","f2": "left"}
  ]},
  {"arry": [ //#3
      {"f1": "yellow","f2": "right"},
      {"f1": "blue","f2": "up"}
  ]},
  {"arry": {"f1": "red","f2": "left"}} //#4
]

The query db.collection.find({"arry.f1":"red"}) will match documents which contain any element in the array where "f1" is "red", and will also match the document where "arry" is an object with such a field, so #1, #2, and #4 match. Playground
The query db.collection.find({"arry":{"$elemMatch":{"f1":"red"}}}) will match documents where "arry" is an array containing an element with the matching field, so #1 and #2. Playground
Querying 2 fields like db.collection.find({"arry.f1":"red","arry.f2":"left"}) will match documents where array is an object or array of objects where "f1" is "red" in at least one element and "f2" is "left" in at least one element (not necessarily the same one), so this would match #1, #2, and #4 again. Playground
Querying 2 fields using elemMatch like db.collection.find({"arry":{"$elemMatch":{"f1":"red","f2":"left"}}}) will match documents where "arry" is an array of objects, and a single object matches both fields, so #1 only. Playground
Now on to indexes.  When an array field is indexed, a separate key is created for each element of the array, and each index key refers to only one element.
Creating an index on {"arry.f1":1, "arry.f2":1} in a collection containing the above documents would result in the index containing keys (| is not really used by mongod as a separator), I've marked which document each refers to:
blue|up      #1
blue|up      #3
green|left   #2
red|left     #1
red|left     #4
red|right    #2
yellow|right #3

Considering the same queries from above:
db.collection.find({"arry.f1":"red"}) - skips to the first instance of "red" in the index, and scans forward through the last, returning documents #1, #4, and #2
db.collection.find({"arry":{"$elemMatch":{"f1":"red"}}}) could use the same plan for starters, but then would have to use a match stage to ensure it only matches arrays.  Depending on how many documents there are in the collection, scanning the index then fetching the documents and matching again may be more work than just doing a collection scan.
For db.collection.find({"arry.f1":"red","arry.f2":"left"}) if the query planner did the naive index scan with range {"arry.f1":["red","red"],"arry.f2":["left","left"]} it would find only documents #1 and #4, which is incorrect since #2 should also match.  In order to find all of the results, it scans the index for the range {"arry.f1":["red","red"],"arry.f2":(MinKey,MaxKey)} which finds all of the documents matching the first predicate, and uses a fetch/match to limit the results to those matching the second.
For db.collection.find({"arry":{"$elemMatch":{"f1":"red","f2":"left"}}}) it can use the index because each index key refers to a single element of the array, and this query limits the matches to be in the same element.  The index scan for the range {"arry.f1":["red","red"],"arry.f2":["left","left"]} finds documents #1 and #4, and the query planner uses a match to eliminate the non-array field, so only #1 is returned.

Thanks for the explanation, makes a lot of sense. But as I understand, and also reading elsewhere, I've understood that $elemMatch somehow always needs a FETCH stage, together with docsExamined, right? And in my case, also querying separately (without $elemMatch) seems to be FETCHing. Isn't there any ways to only use index?

That is true, elemMatch will always use a fetch, but it can also use the index so the only documents fetched are those that match.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63313589/2282634
